# How to display Ruby Functions in Erb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra, erb

I want to display this loop in Sinatra through an ERB file How would I do it.

( Here is the code)

```
puts "Please enter any positive integar from 0"
n = gets.chomp.to_i

def ping_pong(n)
 x = 0.upto(n) {|g|
if g % 3 == 0 && g % 5 == 0
    print "ping-pong" + " " 
elsif g % 3 == 0
    print "ping" + " " 
elsif g % 5 ==0 
    print"pong" + " "
else 
  print "#{g}" +" " 
end
}
  return x
end

ping_pong(n)
```

## I want the Erb file to display the results.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your code will not work fine, because of this line:

```
n = gets.chomp.to_i
```

[Kernel#gets](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Kernel.html#method-i-gets) (which actually calls $stdin) will stop ruby process, on which **sinatra** runs, and will require some input on the console and will block the process until input data received. In case if ruby process is daemonized, this line will raise error. So, you should obtain `n` variable somewhere else. For example by sending this number from html form.

Second. In the method `ping_pong` within the loop there are calls to [`print`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Kernel.html#method-i-print) method, these strings (which `print` method received) will go to $stdout. But you need the ERB buffer, in which send this data in order to display it in browser.
In order to achieve this objective, you can re-implement your method to use ruby blocks and `yield` keyword:

```
def ping_pong(n)
  x = 0.upto(n) do |g|
    if g % 3 == 0 && g % 5 == 0
      yield "ping-pong" + " " 
    elsif g % 3 == 0
      yield "ping" + " " 
    elsif g % 5 ==0 
      yield "pong" + " "
    else 
      yield "#{g}" +" " 
    end
  }
  return x
end
```

This method should be defined within sinatra `helpers` block, to be available in ERB template.

And then in ERB template you should write something like this

```
<% ping_pong(n) do |out| %>
  <%= out %> <!-- Prints "pong" strings -->
<% end %>
```

`<% %>` is only for executing code

`<%= %>` is for executing code and displaying it's return value in rendered result

Answer (score 1):

This code, as is, will not work in an erb file.

Put your functional code inside <% %> tags and the code you want to render (aka the lines with "print") inside <%= %> tags.

Comment: I get the concept of putting the code inside the <% %> tags but if I just put the whole function in the tag, it still won't render. how would you recode it to render? thanks..

Comment: Try putting this method in a helper and then calling <%= ping_pong(5) %> in the view. You shouldn't be writing methods in views.